# How to call an item from graph api fb?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to select an specific field.item from the requested api call and echo it.for example something like this:

```
$getlike = $facebook->api("/fql?q=SELECT%20like_info%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id=".$id);

$getcm = $getlike['data']['like_info']['user_likes'];
echo $getcm;
```

The JSON for the above code:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 70, 
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When i echo the $getcm,it wont return anything.Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array; so you should fetch it like-

```
$getcm = $getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'];
echo $getcm;
```

Comment: $getlike = $facebook->api("/fql?q=SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id=" . $id);
                                $checklike = $getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'];


It does not return anything.

Comment: Blank do you mean? If yes, pls check if you have the permission: `read_stream`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1YWZrZkJJbWE2ZUk/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see i already checked the permission.but still no result at all. :(

Comment: You dont have to set the permissions here, but in the code. Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200251/json-api-graph-call-does-not-return-anything/18200619#18200619

Comment: HELP PLEASE! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215412/how-can-i-like-an-post-using-graph-api