# json api graph call does not return anything?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

i am fetching users fb newfeed and i wanted get check wether user has liked the post or not by using user_likes and the problem is that the following code wont return anything :

```
$getlike = $facebook->api("/fql?q=SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id=" . $id);
$checklike = $getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

here is the complete file: [testone.php](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1MHFTSVFCNC1tWDg/edit?usp=sharing)
the problem is that the fql and calling user_likes wont return anything.
i want to check wether user has liked the post already **OR** how can i get the value for user_likes.

JSON from fb :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 70, 
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

is my technique right?do i need access code or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the value of `$getlike`, you can check the value of `user_likes` like this (since it is of type boolean)-

```
if($getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'])
{
    echo "true";    
}
else 
{
    echo "false";   
}
```

Comment: its showing false for all posts!even the ones i have liked on fb .

Comment: $getlike = $facebook->api("/fql?q=SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id=" . $id);

Can u check my fql,maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: Check out this, i've posted a public post, what result are you getting? `SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id="595273610_10151661287643611"`

Comment: When i run it in fql explorer it runs perfectly,but when i place it in my code,it wont return anything.

Comment: Do u think its related to php sdk or something?

Comment: No, something wrong with your code. What output are you getting with `print_r($getlike)`, I don't think you are even getting any result from the call in your code

Comment: Exactly! ,the problem is calling the fql.i think the technique im using is wrong

Comment: What result are you getting in the response? Could you pls mention

Comment: You might be getting the error regarding `access_token`, if yes then along with the `method` and `query`, pass the parameter `access_token` while making the query. Also, as a good practice, do not write `,` after the last element of the array (in fql query)

Comment: can u give me an example.

Comment: Are you getting the accen_token error? Pls acknowledge to what I'm asking, since am not able to get the status at your end. Here's the ex: `$param = array('method'=> 'fql.query','query' =>$QUERY,'access_token'=> ACCESS_TOKEN,'callback'  => '');`

Comment: Pls search for that, that's the basic thing while integrating the facebook sdk!

Comment: There two access tokens,one for app and another for user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371938/how-do-i-use-fql-with-php-api-and-access-token

Comment: What about this link?

Comment: im testing it,let see what happens.

Comment: look,there is nothing wrong,and it supposed to be working fine,but it does not fetch or shows a single post.

Comment: I cant help, you are not replying to any of my questions. I first asked what's the o/p of `print_r($getlike)`, you didnt reply. Then, access token thing, again you didnt reply. In this way, no body could help you.

Comment: Ok,First,before printing $getlike,i want to put $id in double quotes.
 **$fql = 'SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id=' .$id;**
i tried but i couldnt put result of $id in double quotes.can you help me with this.

Comment: `$fql = 'SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id="'.$id.'";'`

Comment: Alright,now when i echo $getlike,i will get this:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [like_info] => Array ( [can_like] => 1 [like_count] => 34 [user_likes] => ) ) )

Comment: [user_likes] => is empty for all posts.

Comment: I cant understand how that could be empty, can you show me the screenshot of this result. Also, include this per and try again: `user_likes
`

Comment: oooooo,sir i jus found out that for posts i liked,[user_likes] => 1.

Comment: So how can i check the value of user_likes?

Comment: `if($getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'] == 1)
{
    echo "true";    
}`

Comment: then try `echo $getlike['data'][0]` , `echo $getlike['data'][0]['like_info']`, `echo $getlike['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'] `

Comment: When i echo $getlike,it prints Array.

Comment: I know, that's why I said `print_r($getlike)`. Pls follow exactly what I'm saying

Comment: When print($getlike); , it returns this :  Array ( [0] => Array ( [like_info] => Array ( [can_like] => 1 [like_count] => 104 [user_likes] => ) ) )

Comment: and for posts that i liked,it returns this : Array ( [0] => Array ( [like_info] => Array ( [can_like] => 1 [like_count] => 1 [user_likes] => 1 ) ) )

Comment: As you can see there is [user_likes] => 1 for posts i liked and [user_likes] =>    for posts i didnt liked already

Comment: So this is what you want, no? now do this `if($getlike[0]['user_likes'] == 1) echo "1 it is"; else echo "0 it is";`

Comment: 0 it is , for all posts even ones i have liked

Comment: My bad. Try this - `if($getlike[0]['like_info']['user_likes'] == 1) echo "1 it is"; else echo "0 it is";`

PS. pls dont forget to mark the ans if that helped. Also to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187165/how-to-call-an-item-from-graph-api-fb) ques

Comment: WOW ,SIR ITS WORKING! THANK YOU SO MUCH,I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP .I WILL COMMENT IF ANYTHING WENT WRONG . THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215412/how-can-i-like-an-post-using-graph-api